# Paypal issue: PayPal gateway has rejected request. Payment has already been made for this InvoiceID (#10412: Duplicate invoice)

Tags: paypal, magento-2.2.5

In Magento 2.2.5 using Paypal payment.

I am getting the below error:

> PayPal gateway has rejected request. Payment has already been made for this InvoiceID (#10412: Duplicate invoice).

Comment: I discovered that I was having this issue, I do not know for sure if this will be why you are having it but I thought I would share anyway, just in case. I recently reverted my newly launched website back to a previous version, after doing so I was having the error. Before reverting my database I had performed a number of test purchases, after reverting Magento 2 was now creating new orders using the ID numbers that had already been used and paid for before I reverted. Hence the same order ID was being submitted to Paypal. To fix this I made a bunch of orders and paid via a different method (n

Comment: Did you solve your issue? @Saravanan DS